# Retina MBP - "time remaining" not available on menu-bar battery icon?

Tags: macbook-pro

On my new Retina MacBook Pro I'm finding I can't show the time remaining next to the battery icon on the menubar. The option is available in the right-click menu on non-Retina laptops.

Any ideas on how I can get this useful indicator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Battery Time Remaining](https://github.com/codler/Battery-Time-Remaining) is a github-hosted, open source project that aims to solve this problem. From the project page:

> **Battery Time Remaining**
>
> Show the estimated battery time remaining on top of your screen in Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion.
>
> **Why does this project exist?**
>
> Apple removed the option to show the battery time remaining in the statusbar since the Mountain Lion release. This App will do exactly that, show the battery time remaining on top of your screen.
>
> **How do I install it?**
>
> Two options:
>
> - Download [latest version](http://yap.nu/battery-time-remaining/), unzip and run the App
> - Download the source here from Github and compile it with XCode

[image: simple mode] [image: advanced mode]

Comment: This is indeed a good app. However, if you don't know how to compile it using Xcode, you'll need to purchase it on the store. There are also some free alternatives. [TLOB](https://itunes.apple.com/app/tlob-time-left-on-battery/id1229885630?l=en&mt=12), for example, is simple, lightweight and free.

Answer (score 2):

No, it seems that the feature at the moment is unavailable.

Another thread has already checked other ones at the Apple Store and with other customer who have it:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4044409?start=0&tstart=0

It might be something that they add back to it in a software update or in Mountain Lion.  Weird that it is missing though.

Hope that helps.